# How to get a list of data-attribute values from the first row of a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, custom-data-attribute

How can data attributes of a control be read in .NET?

**DESIRED RESULT**

- 1
- 2
- 3

**ASPX**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlItem" runat="server">
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlA" CssClass="pnl-class" data-id="1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlB" CssClass="pnl-class" data-id="2" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlC" CssClass="pnl-class" data-id="3" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub rpt_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpt.ItemDataBound
  If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
    If e.Item.ItemIndex = 0 Then 'First item only
      For Each control As Control In e.Item.FindControl("pnlItem").Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
        'How do you read the attributes from the panel here?
      Next
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

I can easily loop over every panel in the first row but cannot work out how to read the data-attribute of the panel.

Comment: Have you tried using a `Static` variable as a flag to indicate it is the first row? Or are you looking for `someControl.Attributes("data-id")`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton hitting the first row works fine. The problem is reading the data-attribute of the panel.

Comment: It complains that type control doesnt have attributes. Ive tried `htmlGenericControl` and `WebControl` also but cannot locate where the data-attribute field is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that any variable you create in the handler will be re-created on each call to it, unless the variable's scope is larger than the handler.

I used `ctrl As Panel` to make it happy.

```
Private Sub rpt_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpt.ItemDataBound
    Static sb As New StringBuilder()

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        If e.Item.ItemIndex = 0 Then 'First item only
            For Each ctrl As Panel In e.Item.FindControl("pnlItem").Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
                Dim d = ctrl.Attributes("data-id")
                sb.Append(d)
            Next
        End If
    End If

    ' Do something with sb N.B. it is called for every rpt.ItemDataBound event.
    ' "msg" is an asp:Literal I put on the page for testing.
    msg.Text = sb.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: All I had to do was change it to a Panel. Wow. Thank you sir, your a legend.

Comment: @DreamTeK You're welcome :) At first I had used `Dim pnl = DirectCast(ctrl, Panel)` and `pnl.Attributes.Item("data-id")`, then I pared it down and thought `As Control`? -shouldn't that be `As Panel`, seeing as that is what was selected for?